# Why the added view does not appears on the screen?

Tags: android

Look at the code snippet bellow it is for android

```
TableLayout tbL = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.moreInfo_table);
```

`tbL.addView(getRow(key, value), new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                      (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
private TableRow getRow(String key, String value) {
    TableRow tbR = new TableRow(this);
    try {
        TextView keyTV = new TextView(this);
        keyTV.setText("Key " );
        keyTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        keyTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        keyTV.setTextSize(18.0F);
        TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setText("Value " );
        valueTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        valueTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        valueTV.setTextSize(18.0F);     
        tbR.addView(keyTV,new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                  (TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tbR.addView(valueTV,new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                  (TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }       
    return tbR;
}`

Where is the problem??????!!!

Comment: Did you setContentView() the activity?
What are the layout parameters of moreInfo_table in the xml file? Best regards.

Comment: `<TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/moreInfo_table"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/list_selector2"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:stretchColumns="0,1" >`

But it is bart of the main content view

Answer (score 0):

Once try changing the textcolor;;

```
keyTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

to

```
 keyTV.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

might be your view is appearing but due to white color is not visible.

Comment: No, the background color is black

Comment: can you paste your complete xmlfile

Comment: I cannot post the hole xml file, when i tried i had an error in posting it

Comment: just copy&paste it then press ctrl+A then ctrl+K thats all

Comment: I did as you guid me, the full xml file are one of the answers, you can see it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Full xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeName_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Recipe Name..."
        android:textSize="24sp" />
    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/vidThums"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recipeName_view" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/descr"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/vidThums"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ingVu" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/descriptionView"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="The name came from ..., and so forth"
                            android:textSize="24sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ingDet"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/vidThums"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ingVu"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/ingridientsList"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight=".50"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider1"
                        android:dividerHeight="20dp"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_sel1"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/prepMethod"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/vidThums"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ingVu"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/prepMethodList"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider1"
                        android:dividerHeight="20dp"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_sel1"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/moreInfo_table"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/list_selector2"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/noOfPersons" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/noPers_view"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/noOfPersons" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/rating" />

                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/recipRatingBar_details"
                            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:numStars="5"
                            android:rating="3"
                            android:stepSize="0.5" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/prepTime" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/prepTime_view"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="20" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/minutes" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/noOfRater" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/noOfRater_view"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="20" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rating_tab"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/vidThums"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ingVu"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|left"
                        android:text="@string/raterGuid"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/recipRatingBar_rate"                        
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:numStars="5"
                        android:rating="0"
                        android:stepSize="0.5" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/submit"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/vidThums"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/videoThumsHolder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```